# How could I assign a c++ string to another by its reference

Tags: c++, string, reference

I have two c++ strings `std::string dir_1("./dir1"); std::string dir_2("./dir2");` which I need to assign them to another string according to some conditions: `if (...) str = dir_1; else str = dir_2;`.

However, this operations will copy the contents of `dir_1` and `dir_2` which brings some overhead. How could I reduce this overhead ? Is it possible that I only implement the assignment via their references ?

Comment: `std::move` could work. E.g.: `str = std::move(dir_1)`. The memory referenced by `dir_1` will then be referenced by `str` instead. Of course, this assumes `dir_1` and `dir_2` won't be used later.

Comment: You can use the condition operator `?:` in initialization. But why do you care about copying _one_ string so much? Do you fear perfomance lost? (Copying one string?)

Answer (score 6):

Make `str` a reference and use the *ternary operator* to initialize it:

```
const std::string& str = condition ? dir_1 : dir_2;
```

This will not require and copy or move of the original strings.

---

If the condition is more complicated, you can use IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression):

```
const std::string& str = []() -> auto&
{
    if(condition) return dir_1;
    else return dir_2;
}();
```

Or simply refactor the initialization logic to a different function.

Comment: I notice that ```std::string& str ``` can only be initialized only once. Unfortunately, I have to check the condition each loop, so I could not change the reference: ``` for (...) if (condition) str = dir_1; else str = dir_2; ```.  How could I achieve this logic then ?